# "select" statement in stored Procedure is not working

Tags: sql-server

I have tried implementing a stored procedure for displaying the result from different tables by using inner join but my problem is select statement is not returning any result but its printing some of the values as messages.

```
alter proc EmployeeReport(@empid int)
as
begin
declare @inTime time(0)
declare @outTime time(0)
declare @fromDate date
declare @toDate date

set @inTime = (select CAST(InTime as time(0)) from Timelog where EmployeeId=@empid)
set @outTime = (select CAST(OutTime as time(0)) from Timelog where EmployeeId = @empid)
set @fromDate = (select cast (InTime as date) from Timelog where EmployeeId= @empid)
set @toDate = (select cast (outTime as date) from Timelog where EmployeeId= @empid)

select @fromDate as FromDate
      ,@toDate as ToDate
      ,c.Name as Client
      ,p.Name as Project
      ,@inTime as InTime
      ,@outTime as OutTime
      ,t.TotalTime
from Timelog t
    inner join Employee e
        on e.id = t.EmployeeId
    inner join Project p
        on p.Id = t.EmployeeProjectId
    inner join Client c
        on c.Id = p.ClientId
where t.EmployeeId = @empid

 print @inTime
 print @outTime
 print @fromDate
 print @toDate
 end
```

I am attaching the output files what i am getting , please help me with this

Messeges getting printed:

[image]

No values returned or Selected:

[image]

Comment: Check your joins please. Also, where clause missing in your select statement

Comment: i tried using where clause but still not working

Comment: You don't need all those variables you can just select those in your query. And if you want to keep the variables you should do it in one select statement instead of 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial declaration settings only `select` data from your `TimeLog` table, which clearly contains data.  Because you are then `inner join`ing from here to other tables, if those other tables have no data, nothing will be returned.

Either make sure that your `Employee`, `Project` and `Client` tables have data in them or change your `join`s to `left` instead of `inner`:

```
select @fromDate as FromDate
      ,@toDate as ToDate
      ,c.Name as Client
      ,p.Name as Project
      ,@inTime as InTime
      ,@outTime as OutTime
      ,t.TotalTime
from Timelog t
    left join Employee e
        on e.id = t.EmployeeId
    left join Project p
        on p.Id = t.EmployeeProjectId
    left join Client c
        on c.Id = p.ClientId
```